# Receber uma expressão e calcular em C

Tags: c, matemática, parser, eval

Estou desenvolvendo este programinha que deve receber uma expressão do usuário e fazer o cálculo. Ex:

> **Insira uma expressão**
>
> 3*5-1
>
> **14**

O meu problema é como tratar a expressão enviada pelo usuário. Me foi recomendado usar algo como o `eval`, mas não achei nada equivalente na linguagem C. Alguém tem algo equivalente?

Comment: Eu *acho* que eu C não tem `eval`, e que você precisa basicamente construir um parser de expressões matemáticas.

Comment: Em C puro não existe nada, ou você vai ter que escrever sua própria biblioteca, que é algo realmente interessante, vale a pena para aprender, ou procurar alguma biblioteca pronta. O Google me sugeriu essa: http://expreval.sourceforge.net

Comment: Este é um dos "n" motivos pelo qual não se usa linguagem de baixo nível (C, C++) exceto quando muito necessário. Sempre aparece a necessidade de interpretar alguma coisa e sempre é encrenca. O que muitos programas fazem é incorporar um interpretador de uma linguagem mais ou menos consagrada (Javascript, Python, Lua) para tornar-se "Scriptável" e/ou interpretar estruturas de alto nível mais facilmente.

Comment: @epx Linguagens interpretadas têm a facilidade de contar com seu próprio interpretador para resolver expressões. Mas se o tipo de expressão que se deseja avaliar não usar a mesma sintaxe da linguagem, o problema seria o mesmo.

Comment: @epx Além disso, executar `eval` em algo digitado pelo usuário é, no mínimo, perigoso.

Comment: @epx, eu já diria é o contrário: usar uma linguagem interpretada apenas pelo "eval" pode levar a situações de insegurança muito grande no sistema. Usar eval em texto digitado pelo usuário é muito perigoso e pode levar a _code injection_: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#Dynamic_evaluation_vulnerabilities.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal não falei em nenhum momento em usar "eval". Falei de interpretar dados, seja XML, JSON, uma expressão matemática, um arquivo de configuração... tudo isso sempre aparece num sistema de tamanho suficientemente grande.  "Qualquer programa em C ou FORTRAN suficientemente complicado contém uma implementação improvisada, mal especificada, bugada e lenta de metade do Common Lisp."

Comment: `eval`, meu caro amigo, só não é `evil` por causa de uma letra. Ele realmente pode ser do mal, porém os hackers/lammers adoram ele :)

Comment: @epx, existem bibliotecas já com alto nível de desenvolvimento e bem estabelecidas para C que interpretam todos esses tipos de dados que você citou. Se o programador prefere fazer sozinho ao invés de pesquisar uma biblioteca na internet, a culpa não é da linguagem...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Em C não existe um "eval" nem nada similar para executar código em runtime.

Sendo assim a única forma de executar uma expressão como essa é criando uma sub-linguagem. Você precisa definir uma **gramática**, escrever um **parser** e finalmente, criar um **interpretador**. No caso particular de expressões matemáticas, existe um atalho simples, que é o uso da [**notação polonesa inversa**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota%C3%A7%C3%A3o_polonesa_inversa).

Expressões escritas nessa notação são executadas da seguinte forma:

1. Crie uma pilha vazia.
2. Ao ler um número, adicione-o no topo da pilha.
3. Ao ler um operador, retire os dois último elementos da pilha, aplique a operação e adicione o número resultante na mesma.
4. Ao final do processo (sem mais input) deve haver apenas um elemento na pilha, o resultado.

A expressão `3*5-1` seria escrita em notação polonesa inversa como `3 5 * 1 -`. A grande vantagem dessa notação é que parenteses não são necessários. Se a expressão fosse `3*(5-1)`, a polonesa equivalente seria `3 5 1 - *`. Executar esse tipo de expressões é trivial com o algoritmo acima. Agora o real problema: Como transformar uma expressão na notação usual para a notação polonesa inversa?

Para isso existe um algoritmo chamado [**Shunting Yard**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

Assumindo que todos os seus operadores sejam associativos pela esquerda (ou seja: `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`), ele pode ser descrito assim:

- Enquanto houverem símbolos para serem lidos...

  - Se é um número, adicione à saída.
  - Se é um operador (chamemos de `o1`), então:

    - Enquanto existir um operador no topo da pilha temporária (chamemos `o2`) tal que a precedência de `o1` seja menor que `o2`, mova `o2` para a saída.
    - Coloque `o1` na pilha.
  - Se é uma abertura de parênteses, coloque-o na pilha temporária
  - Se é um fechamento de parênteses:

    - Enquanto o topo da pilha temporária não for uma abertura de parênteses, jogue o operador do topo na saída.
    - Remova a abertura de parênteses da pilha temporária.
- Ao não ter mais o que ler, mova todos os operadores da pilha para a saída.

Exemplo:

Considere a expressão `2*3+4*(5-6)`.

Aplicar o Shunting Yard:

```
      Símbolo Lido             Ação              Pilha Temporária         Saída        
    +--------------+---------------------------+------------------+-------------------+
    |      2       | Por na saída              |                  | 2                 |
    +--------------+---------------------------+------------------+-------------------+
    |      *       | Por na pilha              | *                | 2                 |
    +--------------+---------------------------+------------------+-------------------+
    |      3       | Por na saída              | *                | 2 3               |
    +--------------+---------------------------+------------------+-------------------+
    |      +       | Mover da pilha para saída |                  | 2 3 *             |
    |              | Por na pilha              | +                | 2 3 *             |
    +--------------+---------------------------+------------------+-------------------+
    |      4       | Por na saída              | +                | 2 3 * 4           |
    +--------------+---------------------------+------------------+-------------------+
    |      *       | Por na pilha              | + *              | 2 3 * 4           |
    +--------------+---------------------------+------------------+-------------------+
    |      (       | Por na pilha              | + * (            | 2 3 * 4           |
    +--------------+---------------------------+------------------+-------------------+
    |      5       | Por na saída              | + * (            | 2 3 * 4 5         |
    +--------------+---------------------------+------------------+-------------------+
    |      -       | Por na pilha              | + * ( -          | 2 3 * 4 5         |
    +--------------+---------------------------+------------------+-------------------+
    |      6       | Por na saída              | + * ( -          | 2 3 * 4 5 6       |
    +--------------+---------------------------+------------------+-------------------+
    |      )       | Mover da pilha para saída | + * (            | 2 3 * 4 5 6 -     |
    |              | Anular com '('            | + *              | 2 3 * 4 5 6 -     |
    +--------------+---------------------------+------------------+-------------------+
    |              | Pilha toda para saída     |                  | 2 3 * 4 5 6 - * + |
    +--------------+---------------------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

Resultado: `2 3 * 4 5 6 - * +`

Executar como uma notação polonesa inversa:

```
                              Símbolo Lido       Pilha      
                            +--------------+---------------+
                            |      2       | 2             |
                            +--------------+---------------+
                            |      3       | 2 3           |
                            +--------------+---------------+
                            |      *       | 6             |
                            +--------------+---------------+
                            |      4       | 6 4           |
                            +--------------+---------------+
                            |      5       | 6 4 5         |
                            +--------------+---------------+
                            |      6       | 6 4 5 6       |
                            +--------------+---------------+
                            |      -       | 6 4 -1        |
                            +--------------+---------------+
                            |      *       | 6 -4          |
                            +--------------+---------------+
                            |      +       | 2             |
                            +--------------+---------------+
```

Resultado: `2`

Comment: Isso que eu chamo de "Uma Senhora resposta". Parabéns...

Comment: Esse site também é bastante instrutivo: http://www.buildyourownlisp.com/

Answer (score 13):

Se você pode usar algo pronto, veja [libmatheval](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmatheval/) ou a minha biblioteca [ae](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#ae) baseada em Lua.

Com `ae`, basta fazer `v=ae_eval(s)`, onde `s` é um string contendo a expressão a ser avaliada. Essa expressão pode conter variáveis definidas antes. `ae` compila cada expressão uma única vez, o que dilui o custo em avaliações múltiplas. Abaixo um exemplo completo de uso que tabela uma função quadrática:

```
 ae_open();
 ae_set("a",1);
 ae_set("b",-5);
 ae_set("c",6);
 for (x=0.0; x<4.0; x+=0.25)
 {
  ae_set("x",x);
  printf("%g\t%g\n",x,ae_eval("a*x^2+b*x+c"));
 }
 ae_close();
```

Comment: cool! (+1): para além do pedido ainda usa variáveis. Fiquei tambem impressionado com a "libmatheval" (apt-get intalall libmatheval) que desconhecia.

Answer (score 7):

Não existe uma função `eval()` padrão em C. A solução para o seu problema é procurar uma biblioteca que já faça o mesmo que a `eval()` faz ou desenvolver por conta própria uma função que interpreta a expressão e retorne o resultado (o que é bom para o aprendizado).

---

No caso, uma solução simples seria um algoritmo do tipo:

1 - Quebre a expressão em função dos operadores encontrados. Por exemplo:

```
"3*5-1" seria quebrado em [3, *, 5, -, 1]
```

2 - Verifique se não há erros na expressão.

3 - Analise o que é número e o que é operador.

4 - Faça os cálculos entre um elemento da esquerda e um da direita considerando a [precedência](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operadores_em_C_e_C++#Preced.C3.AAncia_de_operadores) que você usará. Por exemplo:

```
3 * 5
```

E depois:

```
15 - 1
```

5 - Repita até ter só um elemento, que será o resultado.

---

Se utilizar parênteses a coisa fica mais complicada, mas é só resolver o que está entre parênteses primeiro. Por exemplo:

```
(3*5 + 2) - 1   =>   17 - 1
```

---

Outra solução mais fácil é integrar seu programa a uma linguagem de script. Dê uma olhada em [Lua](http://www.lua.org/), que é bem fácil de integrar em um programa feito em C.

Answer (score 7):

**Solução baseada em popen**

Ok, ok, admito que é um pouco batota. Mas como esta pergunta foi feita o ano passado, ninguém vai dar por ela :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  char s[100],com[100];
  sprintf(com,"echo '%s'|bc -l",fgets(s,100,stdin));
  FILE* calc=popen(com,"r");
  printf("--> %s",fgets(s,100,calc));
}
```

`popen` permite "comunicar" com um comando externo (neste caso ler a sua saída).
Ver também [manual bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html). Testando:

```
$ calcula
4+4^100
--> 1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301380
```

**E se não estivermos em Linux?**

Se por infelicidade não estivermos em Unix, podemos sempre tentar substituir a linha 4 por:

```
sprintf(com,"ssh uma.maq.unix 'echo \"%s\"| bc -l'",fgets(s,100,stdin));
```

ou instalar Perl e

```
sprintf(com,"perl -e 'print eval \"%s\"'",fgets(s,100,stdin));
```

Answer (score 6):

Minha resposta não vai ser em C, mas espero ajudar numa possível implementação nesta linguagem. ;)

Na maioria das linguagens compiláveis, seja em "código de máquina" ou *bytecode*, há esse problema relacionado à interpretação de fórmulas ou funções de variáveis.

Na época da faculdade eu fiz um interpretador de funções matemáticas com variáveis em Delphi para a matéria de pesquisa operacional e a usei em vários algoritmos de otimização onde você poderia digitar uma função e o programa encontrava o(s) ponto(s) máximo(s) e/ou mínimo(s) dela. Não é tão complicado quanto parece. Uma pena não ter o código-fonte em mãos agora.

Algum tempo depois, já trabalhando com Java, fiz uma outra implementação de uma classe para facilitar a interpretação de expressões simples. Nunca cheguei a usar em produção, então acabou ficando na fase de protótipo, isto é, não foi extensivamente testada, está sujeita a bugs e somente suporta as operações matemáticas mais básicas. Além disso, essa implementação foi feita para Java 1.4, então ela também não usa vários recursos novos da linguagem. Tenho certeza que esse código poderia ser muito melhor, mas talvez ajude para que possa ser criada uma versão em C++.

```java
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.MessageFormat;


/**
 * Calcula o resultado de uma dada expressão, de acordo com os coeficientes definidos.
 * 
 * A expressão é uma fórmula matemática válida, podendo conter os coeficiente (variáveis),
 * operadores ("+", "-", "*", "/" e "^" -> adição, subtração, multiplicação, divisão e 
 * potenciação) e parêntesis. 
 * 
 * Os coeficientes podem ser refenciados na fórmula pelo índice do vetor entre chaves {n} 
 * ou pelas letras de "A" a "Z", sendo "A" equivalente ao índice 0 (zero) do vetor.
 * 
 * Exemplos: "({0} + {1} + {2}) - {3}" ou "(A + B) / (C - D) ^ 2"
 * 
 * Precedência de Operadores (quando não há parêntesis): 
 * 1. Potenciação
 * 2. Multiplicação e Divisão  
 * 3. Adição e subtração
 */
public class Expressao {

    private static int TIPO_NUMERO = 1;
    private static int TIPO_OPERADOR = 2;
    private static int TIPO_PONTO = 3;
    private static int TIPO_LETRA_AZ = 4;
    private static int TIPO_CHAVE_ABRIR = 5;
    private static int TIPO_CHAVE_FECHAR = 6;
    private static int TIPO_PARENTESIS_ABRIR = 7;
    private static int TIPO_PARENTESIS_FECHAR = 8;

    private static String parentesisFaltando = "Parêntesis faltando a partir da posição {0}!";
    private static String valorEsperado = "Coeficiente ou número esperado na posição {0}!";
    private static String numeroEsperado = "Número esperado na posição {0}!";
    private static String indiceEsperado = "Índice de coeficiente esperado na posição {0}!";
    private static String chaveEsperada = "Chave de fechamento esperada na posição {0}!";
    private static String divisaoPorZero = "Divisão por zero na posição {0}!";
    private static String operadorEsperado = "Operador esperado na posição {0}!";
    private static String indiceInvalido = "Índice de coeficiente inválido na posição {0}!";

    private int posExpressao;
    private int tipoElemento;
    private char letra;
    private String expressao;
    private BigDecimal[] coeficientes;


    /**
     * Atalho para execução alternativa
     */
    public static BigDecimal calcular(String expressao, BigDecimal[] coeficientes) {

        try {

            Expressao exp = new Expressao(expressao, coeficientes);
            return exp.calcular(); 

        } catch (Exception e) {

            LogLE.logError(e);
            return Calc.ZERO;

        }

    }

    /**
     * Atalho para execução alternativa
     */
    public static BigDecimal calcular(String expressao, String[] coeficientes) {
        try {
            Expressao exp = new Expressao(expressao, coeficientes);
            return exp.calcular(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Calc.ZERO;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Atalho para execução alternativa
     */
    public static BigDecimal calcular(String expressao, Object[] coeficientes) {

        try {

            Expressao exp = new Expressao(expressao, coeficientes);
            return exp.calcular(); 

        } catch (Exception e) {

            LogLE.logError(e);
            return Calc.ZERO;

        }

    }


    /**
     * Constrói um avaliador para a expressão e respectivos coeficientes (variáveis)
     * 
     * Exemplo: new Expressao("(A + B + C) - D", new BigDecimal[] {v1, v2, v3, v4} 
     */
    public Expressao(String expressao, BigDecimal[] coeficientes) throws Exception  {

        this.expressao = expressao.replaceAll("\\s", "").toUpperCase();
        this.coeficientes = coeficientes;
        this.posExpressao = -1;

    }

    /**
     * Constrói um avaliador para a expressão e respectivos coeficientes (variáveis)
     * 
     * Exemplo: new Expressao("({0} + {1} + {2}) - {3}", new String[] {s1, s2, s3, s4}
     */
    public Expressao(String expressao, String[] coeficientes) throws Exception  {

        this.expressao = expressao.replaceAll("\\s", "").toUpperCase();
        this.coeficientes = new BigDecimal[coeficientes.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < coeficientes.length; i++) {
            this.coeficientes[i] = Calc.toBigDecimal(coeficientes[i]);
        }
        this.posExpressao = -1;

    }

    /**
     * Constrói um avaliador para a expressão e respectivos coeficientes (variáveis)
     * Os coeficientes podem ser String, BigDecimal, Integer ou Double 
     * 
     * Exemplo: new Expressao("({0} + {1} + {2}) - {3}", new Object[] {o1, o2, o3, o4}
     */
    public Expressao(String expressao, Object[] coeficientes) throws Exception  {

        this.expressao = expressao.replaceAll("\\s", "").toUpperCase();
        this.coeficientes = new BigDecimal[coeficientes.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < coeficientes.length; i++) {
            if (coeficientes[i] == null) {
                this.coeficientes[i] = Calc.ZERO;
            } else if (coeficientes[i] instanceof String) {
                this.coeficientes[i] = Calc.toBigDecimal((String) coeficientes[i]);
            } else if (coeficientes[i] instanceof BigDecimal) {
                this.coeficientes[i] = Calc.toBigDecimal((BigDecimal) coeficientes[i]);
            } else if (coeficientes[i] instanceof Double) {
                this.coeficientes[i] = Calc.toBigDecimal(((Double) coeficientes[i]).doubleValue());
            } else if (coeficientes[i] instanceof Integer) {
                this.coeficientes[i] = Calc.toBigDecimal(((Integer) coeficientes[i]).intValue());
            } else {
                //tenta converter o objeto para String e depois para BigDecimal
                this.coeficientes[i] = Calc.toBigDecimal(coeficientes[i].toString());
            }
        }
        this.posExpressao = -1;

    }   

    //retorna verdadeiro se o próximo caracter for o início de um valor válido com ou sem sinal
    private boolean ehValorSinal() {

        return tipoElemento == TIPO_NUMERO || tipoElemento == TIPO_CHAVE_ABRIR || tipoElemento == TIPO_PARENTESIS_ABRIR || 
            (tipoElemento == TIPO_OPERADOR && (letra == '+' || letra == '-') || tipoElemento == TIPO_LETRA_AZ);

    }


    /**
     * Avalia a expressão de acordo com os coeficientes definidos e retorna o resultado
     */
    public BigDecimal calcular() throws Exception {

        BigDecimal resposta = Calc.ZERO;
        proximoElemento();

        if (!EOF()) {
            if (!ehValorSinal()) {
                Erro(valorEsperado);
            }
            resposta = expressaoPrecedencia();
        }

        while (!EOF()) {

            if (tipoElemento == TIPO_OPERADOR) {
                char operador = letra;
                proximoElemento();

                if (!ehValorSinal()) {
                    Erro(valorEsperado);
                }
                BigDecimal outroValor = expressaoPrecedencia();

                if (operador == '+') {
                    resposta = Calc.soma(resposta, outroValor);
                } else if (operador == '-') {
                    resposta = Calc.subtrai(resposta, outroValor);
                }
            } else {
                Erro(operadorEsperado);
            }

        }
        return resposta;
    }

    //avalia uma expressão com precedência 1, atualmente multiplicação e divisão (analisador sintático)
    private BigDecimal expressaoPrecedencia() throws Exception {

        BigDecimal resposta = expressaoPrecedencia2();
        while (!EOF() && (tipoElemento == TIPO_OPERADOR && (letra == '*' || letra == '/'))) {

            char operador = letra;
            proximoElemento();
            if (ehValorSinal()) {

                BigDecimal outroValor = expressaoPrecedencia2(); 
                if (operador == '*') {
                    resposta = Calc.multiplica(resposta, outroValor);
                } else if (operador == '/') {
                    if (Calc.ehZero(outroValor)) {
                        Erro(divisaoPorZero);
                    }
                    resposta = Calc.divide(resposta, outroValor);
                }

            }

        }
        return resposta;

    }

    //avalia uma expressão com precedência 2, atualmente a potenciação (analisador sintático)
    private BigDecimal expressaoPrecedencia2() throws Exception {

        BigDecimal resposta = valorSinal();
        while (!EOF() && (tipoElemento == TIPO_OPERADOR && letra == '^')) {

            char operador = letra;
            proximoElemento();
            if (ehValorSinal()) {

                BigDecimal outroValor = valorSinal(); 
                if (operador == '^') {
                    resposta = Calc.potencia(resposta, outroValor);
                }

            }

        }
        return resposta;

    }       

    //avalia um valor válido na expressão com ou sem um operador unitário (analisador sintático)
    private BigDecimal valorSinal() throws Exception {

        //operador unitário
        if (tipoElemento == TIPO_OPERADOR && (letra == '+' || letra == '-')) {

            char operadorUnitario = letra;
            proximoElemento();
            BigDecimal valor = valor();
            if (operadorUnitario == '-') {
                valor = Calc.multiplica(valor, -1);
            }
            return valor;

        } else {
            return valor();
        }

    }

    //avalia um valor válido na expressão: {n}, 9.99, 9.99, (...), A (analisador sintático)
    private BigDecimal valor() throws Exception {

        if (tipoElemento == TIPO_PARENTESIS_ABRIR) {

            int numParentesis = 1;
            int posIni = posExpressao + 1;
            do {
                proximoElemento();
                if (letra == '(') {
                    numParentesis++;
                } else if (letra == ')') {
                    numParentesis--;
                }
            } while (numParentesis > 0 && posExpressao < expressao.length());

            if (posExpressao >= expressao.length()) {
                Erro(parentesisFaltando);
            } else {
                proximoElemento();
                Expressao exp = new Expressao(Texto.cortar(expressao, posIni, posExpressao - posIni - 1), coeficientes);
                return exp.calcular();
            }

        } else if (tipoElemento == TIPO_CHAVE_ABRIR) {

            //coeficiente
            proximoElemento();
            if (EOF() || tipoElemento != TIPO_NUMERO) {
                Erro(indiceEsperado);
            }
            int indice = numeroInteiro();
            if (EOF() || tipoElemento != TIPO_CHAVE_FECHAR) {
                Erro(chaveEsperada);
            }
            if (indice >= coeficientes.length || indice < 0) {
                Erro(indiceInvalido);
            }
            proximoElemento();
            return Calc.toBigDecimal(coeficientes[indice]);

        } else if (tipoElemento == TIPO_NUMERO) {

            //número
            return numeroReal();

        } else if (tipoElemento == TIPO_LETRA_AZ) {

            int indice = letra - 'A';
            if (indice >= coeficientes.length || indice < 0) {
                Erro(indiceInvalido);
            }
            proximoElemento();
            return Calc.toBigDecimal(coeficientes[indice]);

        }

        Erro(valorEsperado);
        return null;
    }

    //avalia um número real no formato 9.99 (analisador sintático)
    private BigDecimal numeroReal() throws Exception {

        String numero = numeroTexto();
        if (!EOF() && tipoElemento == TIPO_PONTO) {
            proximoElemento();
            if (!EOF() && tipoElemento == TIPO_NUMERO) {
                numero += "," + numeroTexto();
            } else {
                Erro(numeroEsperado);
            }
        }

        return Calc.toBigDecimal(numero);  

    }

    //avalia um número inteiro (analisador sintático)
    private int numeroInteiro() {

        return Integer.parseInt(numeroTexto());

    }

    //avalia uma sequência de caracteres numéricos (analisador sintático)
    private String numeroTexto() {

        String num = new String(new char[] {letra}); 
        do {
            proximoElemento();
            if (!EOF() && tipoElemento == TIPO_NUMERO) {
                num += letra;
            }
        } while (!EOF() && tipoElemento == TIPO_NUMERO);
        return num;

    }


    //analisador léxico
    private void proximoElemento() {

        if (posExpressao < expressao.length() - 1) {
            letra = expressao.charAt(++posExpressao);
        } else {
            posExpressao++;
            letra = 0;
        }

        tipoElemento = 0;
        switch (letra) {
            case '{':
                tipoElemento = TIPO_CHAVE_ABRIR;
                break;

            case '}':
                tipoElemento = TIPO_CHAVE_FECHAR;
                break;

            case '(':
                tipoElemento = TIPO_PARENTESIS_ABRIR;
                break;

            case ')':
                tipoElemento = TIPO_PARENTESIS_FECHAR;
                break;

            case '.':
                tipoElemento = TIPO_PONTO;
                break;

            case '+':
            case '-':
            case '*':
            case '/':
            case '^':
            case '%':
                tipoElemento = TIPO_OPERADOR;
                break;

            default:
                if (letra >= 'A' && letra <= 'Z') {
                    tipoElemento = TIPO_LETRA_AZ;
                } else if (letra >= '0' && letra <= '9') {
                    tipoElemento = TIPO_NUMERO;
                }
                break;
        }

    }

    //verifica se chegou ao final da expressão
    private boolean EOF() {

        return posExpressao >= expressao.length()   ;

    }

    //lança um erro (Exception com descrição) quando encontrar qualquer problema na avaliação da expressão
    private void Erro(String mensagem) throws Exception {

        throw new Exception(MessageFormat.format(mensagem, new Object[] { Calc.imprimeInt(posExpressao) }));

    }


    //rotinas de inicialização de vetor com Strings

    public static BigDecimal[] getVetor(String v1, String v2) {
        return new BigDecimal[] {Calc.toBigDecimal(v1), Calc.toBigDecimal(v2)};
    }

    public static BigDecimal[] getVetor(String v1, String v2, String v3) {
        return new BigDecimal[] {Calc.toBigDecimal(v1), Calc.toBigDecimal(v2), Calc.toBigDecimal(v3)};
    }

    public static BigDecimal[] getVetor(String v1, String v2, String v3, String v4) {
        return new BigDecimal[] {Calc.toBigDecimal(v1), Calc.toBigDecimal(v2), Calc.toBigDecimal(v3), Calc.toBigDecimal(v4)};
    }

    public static BigDecimal[] getVetor(String v1, String v2, String v3, String v4, String v5) {
        return new BigDecimal[] {Calc.toBigDecimal(v1), Calc.toBigDecimal(v2), Calc.toBigDecimal(v3), 
                Calc.toBigDecimal(v4), Calc.toBigDecimal(v5)};
    }

    public static BigDecimal[] getVetor(String v1, String v2, String v3, String v4, String v5, String v6) {
        return new BigDecimal[] {Calc.toBigDecimal(v1), Calc.toBigDecimal(v2), Calc.toBigDecimal(v3), 
                Calc.toBigDecimal(v4), Calc.toBigDecimal(v5), Calc.toBigDecimal(v6)};
    }


    //com BigDecimals

    public static BigDecimal[] getVetor(BigDecimal v1, BigDecimal v2) {
        return new BigDecimal[] {v1, v2};
    }

    public static BigDecimal[] getVetor(BigDecimal v1, BigDecimal v2, BigDecimal v3) {
        return new BigDecimal[] {v1, v2, v3};
    }

    public static BigDecimal[] getVetor(BigDecimal v1, BigDecimal v2, BigDecimal v3, BigDecimal v4) {
        return new BigDecimal[] {v1, v2, v3, v4};
    }

    public static BigDecimal[] getVetor(BigDecimal v1, BigDecimal v2, BigDecimal v3, BigDecimal v4, BigDecimal v5) {
        return new BigDecimal[] {v1, v2, v3, v4, v5};
    }

    public static BigDecimal[] getVetor(BigDecimal v1, BigDecimal v2, BigDecimal v3, BigDecimal v4, BigDecimal v5, BigDecimal v6) {
        return new BigDecimal[] {v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6};
    }

    //com Objects

    public static Object[] getVetor(Object v1, Object v2) {
        return new Object[] {v1, v2};
    }

    public static Object[] getVetor(Object v1, Object v2, Object v3) {
        return new Object[] {v1, v2, v3};
    }

    public static Object[] getVetor(Object v1, Object v2, Object v3, Object v4) {
        return new Object[] {v1, v2, v3, v4};
    }

    public static Object[] getVetor(Object v1, Object v2, Object v3, Object v4, Object v5) {
        return new Object[] {v1, v2, v3, v4, v5};
    }

    public static Object[] getVetor(Object v1, Object v2, Object v3, Object v4, Object v5, Object v6) {
        return new Object[] {v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6};
    }

}
```

Acho que esse é o tipo de interpretador mais simples e menos eficiente que existe. Não lembro exatamente da teoria, mas aprendi na matéria de compiladores na faculdade e sempre trouxe um código custo-benefício no sentido de que é simples para implementar e atende bem requisitos mais simples. Ou seja, não é bom para implementar uma HP12C (se quiser uma, vá no [site do @epx](http://epx.com.br/)), nem cálculos para a bolsa de valores.

Esta técnica consiste basicamente em implementar um analisador sintático com um método para cada regra da gramática, das mais complexas até as mais simples.

Se alguém tiver algo a complementar, fique à vontade para comentar.