# Criando um Interpretador java para android?

Tags: java, android-studio, otimização, bytecode

Eu estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo android onde será possível escrever um código java e executálo... algo parecido com o [visualg](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visualg).
então eu fiz algo diferente do que a maioria dos tutoriais sobre compiladores e pseudocódigos diriam... onde que teria que ser gerado um código de máquina escrito em assembly, ou talvez apenas um java bytecode...
no pc :(texto --> código intermediário --> código de máquina --> Executa)
no android:(*.java --> java.class --> classes.dex --> ART interpreta -->Executa)

 
mas como a criação de um compilador desse tipo é complexa demais decidi fazer um interpretador em tempo de execução, e o que ele faz é compilar o texto em "micro-operacoes", como por exemplo, Soma, Subtracao, Multiplicacao, Println, etc...
então ele faz o seguinte:
(texto --> cria microperacoes --> executa cada microperacao)

a estrutura do interpretador é parecida com isso:[image: Diagrama geral mal modelado]
agora queria saber de vocês se existe uma forma de otimizar esse codigo,
fazendo alguns testes com o emulador, vi que é possível executar até uns 79 milhões de micro-operações em 1 segundo, o que dá umas 12 vezes mais lento que um processador real de 1.0 gigaherts.
mas queria descobrir se o modo que montei isso tudo é realmente algo novo ou se existem linguagens interpretadas que funcionem de forma parecida com esta (devem consumir muita memoria RAM)

alguma sugestão de como melhorar/otimizar esse projeto?
exemplo de uma das classes executavel (todas as outras sao iguais só muda o tipo e o operador)

```
public final class SomarDoubles extends Executavel {

final WDouble a;
final WDouble b;
final WDouble c;
public SomarDoubles(WDouble a, WDouble b,WDouble c)
{
this.a = a;
this.b = b;
this.c = c;
}
@Override
final public void Executar() {
    c.valor = a.valor+b.valor;
}
}
```

exemplo de uma classe de tipo (mesma coisa, só muda o valor contido):

```
public final class WByte extends Valor {
byte valor = 0;
public WByte(byte v) {
    this.valor = v;
}
// métodos de casting:
@Override
final public short Short() {
    return valor;
}

@Override
final public char Char() {
    return (char)valor;
}
// etc...
}
```

e o codigo na hora de executar (a compilação é feita antes e manda o array e instrucoes)

```
public class Executar extends Thread{

private final Executavel[] instrucoes;
private final int length;
public static int i=0;
public Executar(Executavel[] instrucoes)
{
super();
this.instrucoes = instrucoes;
length = instrucoes.length;
}

@Override
final public void run()
{   
i=0;    
long delay = System.nanoTime();
long k=0;
try {
    while(i<length)
    {
    instrucoes[i++].Executar();
    k++;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
long agora=  System.nanoTime();
double tempo = (agora-delay);
System.out.println("emulado : executou "+k+" instrucoes em "+tempo/1000000.0d+" milisegundos ("+tempo/1000000000.0d+" segundos), o que d� \n"
        + " aproximadamente "+tempo/k+" nanosegundos por instrucao");

}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Compilador vs. Interpretador

Não há problema algum em criar interpretadores para uma determinada linguagem ou um subconjunto dela.

Sua abordagem está correta dentro de algumas condições:

1. Seu interpretador realmente atende suas necessidades. Certamente não daria para emular toda a linguagem Java dessa forma, mas um conjunto de instruções simplificadas.
2. O interpretador atende seus requisitos de desempenho. Com certeza interpretar ou emular é sempre mais lento do que ter um código compilado, mas em muitos casos isso será imperceptível para o usuário se for usado com moderação em pontos específicos e armazenando os resultados em *cache* quando possível.

## Defina exatamente o escopo da sua linguagem

Pelo que entendi, você não precisa de todos os recursos do Java, mas principalmente algumas expressões e também comandos de impressão.

Nesse caso, especifique exatamente a sintaxe e a gramática dessa sublinguagem derivada do Java e considere se será possível implementar todas as funcionalidades necessários.

Não sei como está fazendo a interpretação do código, mas ainda que não esteja criando um compilador, você vai usar a teoria de compiladores, pois já deve ter criado ou vai precisar criar analisadores léxicos, sintáticos e semânticos.

Se, por acaso, você está interpretando a linguagem usando *regex*, *split* ou *substring* vai ter problemas em várias situações, por exemplo, se houver vários níveis de parêntesis nas expressões matemáticas.

Enfim, criar um interpretador, mesmo que somente para um escopo bem reduzido como expressões matemáticas não é totalmente trivial a menos que você tenha uma boa base teórica ou pelo menos prática sobre o assunto.

[Veja um exemplo de um interpretador de expressões nesta minha outra resposta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6431/227)

## Outras opções

Caso precise realmente executar algum código mais complexo e não quer reinventar a roda, considere usar um interpretador existente.

Existem várias bibliotecas em Java que podem lhe ajudar:

### Rhino

Este é interpretador JavaScript implementado em Java. [Veja um artigo](https://vec.io/posts/embed-javascript-in-android-java-code-with-rhino) sobre como usar ele no Android. [Aqui tem outro](http://divineprogrammer.blogspot.in/2009/11/javascript-rhino-on-android.html).

Aqui um exemplo:

```java
public void runScript() {
    // Get the JavaScript in previous section
    String source = getScriptFromServer();
    String functionName = "hello";
    Object[] functionParams = new Object[] { "Android" };

    // Every Rhino VM begins with the enter()
    // This Context is not Android's Context
    Context rhino = Context.enter();

    // Turn off optimization to make Rhino Android compatible
    rhino.setOptimizationLevel(-1);
    try {
        Scriptable scope = rhino.initStandardObjects();

    // This line set the javaContext variable in JavaScript
    ScriptableObject.putProperty(scope, "javaContext", Context.javaToJS(androidContextObject, scope));

        // Note the forth argument is 1, which means the JavaScript source has
    // been compressed to only one line using something like YUI
        rhino.evaluateString(scope, RHINO_LOG + source, "ScriptAPI", 1, null);

        // We get the hello function defined in JavaScript
        Function function = (Function) scope.get(functionName, scope);

    // Call the hello function with params
        NativeObject result = (NativeObject) function.call(rhino, scope, scope, functionParams));
    // After the hello function is invoked, you will see logcat output

    // Finally we want to print the result of hello function
    String foo = (String) Context.jsToJava(result.get("foo", result), String.class);
    log(foo);
    } finally {
    // We must exit the Rhino VM
        Context.exit();
    }
}
```

### Java Expression Language (JEXL)

O [JEXL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/) é uma biblioteca que implementa uma linguagem de expressões baseadas na JSTL, parecido com que temos nos JSPs.

Exemplo:

```java
// Assuming we have a JexlEngine instance initialized in our class named 'jexl':
// Create an expression object for our calculation
String calculateTax = taxManager.getTaxCalc(); //e.g. "((G1 + G2 + G3) * 0.1) + G4";
Expression e = jexl.createExpression( calculateTax );

// populate the context
JexlContext context = new MapContext();
context.set("G1", businessObject.getTotalSales());
context.set("G2", taxManager.getTaxCredit(businessObject.getYear()));
context.set("G3", businessObject.getIntercompanyPayments());
context.set("G4", -taxManager.getAllowances());
// ...

// work it out
Float result = (Float)e.evaluate(context);
```

### Velocity

O [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) é uma biblioteca de templates, mas também pode ser usada para executar expressões e trechos de código numa sintaxe especial

A documentação diz [como você pode usá-lo](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/developer-guide.html#Using_Velocity) dentro de uma aplicação Java, além de prover uma [referência sobre a linguagem](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/user-guide.html).

Exemplo de como executar o Velocity:

```java
/* first, we init the runtime engine.  Defaults are fine. */

Velocity.init();

/* lets make a Context and put data into it */

VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();

context.put("name", "Velocity");
context.put("project", "Jakarta");

/* lets render a template */

StringWriter w = new StringWriter();

Velocity.mergeTemplate("testtemplate.vm", context, w );
System.out.println(" template : " + w );

/* lets make our own string to render */

String s = "We are using $project $name to render this.";
w = new StringWriter();
Velocity.evaluate( context, w, "mystring", s );
System.out.println(" string : " + w );
```

### MVEL

O [Apache MVEL](http://mvel.codehaus.org/Integration+Guide+for+2.0) é outra biblioteca de linguagem de expressões.

Você pode conhecer a [sintaxe da linguagem na documentação](http://mvel.codehaus.org/Language+Guide+for+2.0), além de [integrá-la ao seu programa facilmente](http://mvel.codehaus.org/Integration+Guide+for+2.0).

Exemplo:

```java
 String expression = "foobar > 99";

 Map vars = new HashMap();
 vars.put("foobar", new Integer(100));

 // We know this expression should return a boolean.
 Boolean result = (Boolean) MVEL.eval(expression, vars);

 if (result.booleanValue()) {
     System.out.println("It works!");
}
```

O MVEL permite "compilar" a expressão para melhor desempenho se reusada e também forçar a verificação de tipos de variáveis para evitar erros durante a execução.

Comment: Valeu por me responder tão rápido e com várias fontes. com certeza interpretar é mais lento, mas será utilizado com "moderação", afinal será executado em um aplicativo android com finalidade apenas de aprendizado, se o código leva 0.4 nanosegundos ou 60 nanosegundos para somar 2 inteiros não faz muita diferença...

Comment: se quer saber como interpreto eu utilizo a notação do Reverse Polish Notation (não usa parenteses) conversor: http://andreinc.net/2010/10/05/converting-infix-to-rpn-shunting-yard-algorithm/ resolvedor: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/ReversePolishNotation.htm  eu apenas adaptei e expandi esses dois algoritmos para que pudessem suportar a maioria dos operadores de programação ( =, <= ,>= , ==, *=, /=, etc... ) e ao invés de calcular salvar a operação como um objeto de um dos tipos filhos de Executavel com os valores a,b, e c, que são adicionados ao array