# Como realizar uma expressão algébrica em uma string em C

Tags: c, matemática, parser

O meu programa tem o seguinte objetivo:

Dada uma função, o meu programa substitui o(s) 'X(s)' da função por um número qualquer.

O código abaixo exemplifica o que foi dito.

```
//funcao a ser trabalhada
char funcao[150]  = "(x^2)*5";
int tamanho = strlen(funcao);

//Substitui o x da funcao por um valor dado
    for(int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
        if(funcao[i] == 'x')
            funcao[i] = '2';
    }
```

O resultado deste procedimento me retorna a string "(2^2)*5".

Como realizar o cálculo desta equação?

Comment: Só com esta informação não dá para ajudar. Além de detalhar mais o seu código, coloque o que já fez, o que tentou. Mas já te adianto que você vai ter que criar um *parser*, o que não é algo trivial.

Comment: Qual a complexidade dessa expressão? Imagino que ela tenha no mínimo adição, subtração, multiplicação e divisão, e o que mais? Parênteses? Outras funções? Etc. Um tempo atrás eu [respondi uma pergunta semelhante](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43886/215), mas em JavaScript, não em C. Sugiro dar uma olhada lá, talvez dê uma ajuda.

Comment: @bigown Para o caso de expressões aritméticas pode não ser necessário ir tão longe a ponto de criar um *parser* - a conversão da expressão para a [notação Polonesa reversa (pós-fixada ou posfixa)](http://www.sergio.pro.br/trabalhos/17_avaliacao_de_expressoes_em_estrutura_de_dados.pdf) e subsequente avaliação pode ser suficiente.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Não seria um *parser*, ainda que simplificado?

Comment: @bigown De fato. Na minha cabeça uma [tradução dirigida por sintaxe](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Constru%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_compiladores/Tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o_dirigida_por_sintaxe) era algo diferente - mais simples - do que o que a gente normalmente entende por *parsing* (cuja saída costuma ser uma representação abstrata dos dados). Mas você tem razão, mesmo isso não deixa de ser um *parser*.

Comment: Talvez um [eval](http://www8.cs.umu.se/~isak/Snippets/eval.c) te ajude.

Comment: Ou talvez esta [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6382/receber-uma-express%C3%A3o-e-calcular-em-c).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se não estás limitado ao standard básico e podes usar POSIX (que descreve a função [popen()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html)), então passa a string para uma calculadora externa, por exemplo *bc*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int calculo(const char *expression) {
    FILE *bc;
    char command[1000];
    char result[1000];

    snprintf(command, sizeof command, "echo '%s' | bc", expression);
    bc = popen(command, "r");
    if (!bc) return -1;
    if (!fgets(result, sizeof result, bc)) return -1;
    pclose(bc);
    return strtol(result, NULL, 10);
}

int main(void) {
    // funcao a ser trabalhada
    char funcao[150] = "(x^2)*5";
    int tamanho = strlen(funcao);

    // Substitui o x da funcao por um valor dado
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
        if (funcao[i] == 'x') funcao[i] = '2';
    }
    int valor = calculo(funcao);
    printf("%s ==> %d\n", funcao, valor);
    return 0;
}
```

Na minha máquina, o resultado do executável é

```
% ./a.out
(2^2)*5 ==> 20
```

Comment: A minha função `calculo()` é muito básica! Ela devia arranjar uma forma diferente de devolver erros, a passagem de strings para a shell devia ser protegida.

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu estava querendo. Se encaixou perfeitamente no meu programa

Answer (score 6):

As maneiras usuais de se resolver esse problema é ou escrevendo um *parser* (como [sugerido por Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88885/como-realizar-uma-express%C3%A3o-alg%C3%A9brica-em-uma-string-em-c#comment179523_88885); um exemplo simples - em JavaScript - [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43886/215)) que gere uma representação abstrata dos dados, ou talvez convertendo a expressão para a [Notação Polonesa Inversa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota%C3%A7%C3%A3o_polonesa_inversa) em um processo de *parsing* mais simples e então avaliando-a (aqui tem [um PDF](http://www.sergio.pro.br/trabalhos/17_avaliacao_de_expressoes_em_estrutura_de_dados.pdf) com instruções, em Pascal - não conheço bem a fonte, achei no Google).

A primeira forma é mais flexível (na pergunta relacionada, o resultado foi usado para resolver equações simples do segundo grau), mas a segunda é mais simples. Vou dar uma explicação *bem* simplificada aqui (pois implementar em C é meio chatinho, ainda mais pra mim que tenho pouca experiência) junto com links para referências de implementação, para que você possa estudá-las mais a fundo.

1. O objetivo da notação posfixa é passar todos os operadores pro final - e não pro meio - dos seus operandos. Por exemplo a expressão:

   > 1 + 2 * 3

   Ficaria assim na notação posfixa:

   ```
   1 2 3 * +
   ```

   Já a expressão:

   > (1 + 2) * 3

   Ficaria assim:

   ```
   1 2 + 3 *
   ```

   Etc. Para interpretar essas expressões, considere que cada operador se aplica aos dois últimos operandos lidos, retirando-os da lista e substituindo a todos pelo resultado da operação. O operador seguinte faz o mesmo, e o processo continua até que só sobre um único número na lista (mais detalhes adiante).

   Uma vantagem dessa notação é que os parênteses são desnecessários - qualquer expressão pode ser representada de uma forma que o cálculo ocorra na ordem correta desejada.

   - A conversão entre os formatos infixo e posfixo pode ser feita através do [algoritmo de shunting-yard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

     Para entendê-lo, considere que cada operador possui tanto uma **precedência** quanto uma **associatividade**: vezes aplica antes de mais, por exemplo, e ambos se associam à esquerda. `A - B - C` se aplica como `(A - B) - C` e não como `A - (B - C)`, mas `A^B^C` se aplica como `A^(B^C)` e não o contrário. Sub-expressões entre parênteses se aplicam antes do resto.

     O algoritmo funciona lendo cada *token* (número, operador, abre parêntese ou fecha parêntese) da entrada e então colocando-o ou na saída ou em uma pilha. Números vão sempre pra saída. Operadores vão pra pilha, mas antes eles retiram da pilha (mandando pra saída) qualquer operador cuja precedência seja menor ou menor-ou-igual a ele (dependendo da associatividade). Abre parênteses vão pra pilha, e fecha parênteses desmpilha tudo até o abre parênteses correspondente e joga na saída.

     ```
     1 + 2 * 3     []
     _ + 2 * 3     []       1
       _ 2 * 3     [+]      1
         _ * 3     [+]      1 2
           _ 3     [+, *]   1 2
             _     [+, *]   1 2 3
                   [+]      1 2 3 *
                   []       1 2 3 * +

     (1 + 2) * 3   []
     _1 + 2) * 3   [(]
      _ + 2) * 3   [(]      1
        _ 2) * 3   [(, +]   1
          _) * 3   [(, +]   1 2
           _ * 3   []       1 2 +
             _ 3   [*]      1 2 +
               _   [*]      1 2 + 3
                   []       1 2 + 3 *

     1 + 2*3 / (4 ^ (5+6) )   []
     _ + 2*3 / (4 ^ (5+6) )   []                   1
       _ 2*3 / (4 ^ (5+6) )   [+]                  1
         _*3 / (4 ^ (5+6) )   [+]                  1 2
          _3 / (4 ^ (5+6) )   [+, *]               1 2
           _ / (4 ^ (5+6) )   [+, *]               1 2 3
             _ (4 ^ (5+6) )   [+, /]               1 2 3 *
               _4 ^ (5+6) )   [+, /, (]            1 2 3 *
                _ ^ (5+6) )   [+, /, (]            1 2 3 * 4
                  _ (5+6) )   [+, /, (, ^]         1 2 3 * 4
                    _5+6) )   [+, /, (, ^, (]      1 2 3 * 4
                     _+6) )   [+, /, (, ^, (]      1 2 3 * 4 5
                      _6) )   [+, /, (, ^, (, +]   1 2 3 * 4 5
                       _) )   [+, /, (, ^, (, +]   1 2 3 * 4 5 6
                        _ )   [+, /, (, ^]         1 2 3 * 4 5 6 +
                          _   [+, /]               1 2 3 * 4 5 6 + ^
                              [+]                  1 2 3 * 4 5 6 + ^ /
                              []                   1 2 3 * 4 5 6 + ^ / +
     ```

     [Exemplo em C no rosettacode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Parsing/Shunting-yard_algorithm#C).
2. Para avaliar uma expressão na notação posfixa, é necessário usar uma pilha. Cada elemento lido é empilhado, caso seja um número, e se for um operador ele desempilha dois números e aplica o operador no mesmo:

   ```
   1 2 3 * +    []
   _ 2 3 * +    [1]
     _ 3 * +    [1, 2]
       _ * +    [1, 2, 3]
         _ +    [1, (2*3)] -> [1, 6]
           _    [(1+6)]    -> [7]

   1 2 + 3 *    []
   _ 2 + 3 *    [1]
     _ + 3 *    [1, 2]
       _ 3 *    [(1+2)] -> [3]
         _ *    [3, 3]
           _    [(3*3)] -> [9]

   1 2 3 * 4 5 6 + ^ / +   []
   _ 2 3 * 4 5 6 + ^ / +   [1]
     _ 3 * 4 5 6 + ^ / +   [1, 2]
       _ * 4 5 6 + ^ / +   [1, 2, 3]
         _ 4 5 6 + ^ / +   [1, (2*3)] -> [1, 6]
           _ 5 6 + ^ / +   [1, 6, 4]
             _ 6 + ^ / +   [1, 6, 4, 5]
               _ + ^ / +   [1, 6, 4, 5, 6]
                 _ ^ / +   [1, 6, 4, (5+6)] -> [1, 6, 4, 11]
                   _ / +   [1, 6, (4^11)] -> [1, 6, 4194304]
                     _ +   [1, (6/4194304)] -> [1, 0.00000143]
                       _   [(1+0.00000143)] -> [1.00000143]
   ```

   [Exemplo em C no rosettacode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Parsing/RPN_calculator_algorithm#C).