# Como fazer um programa para calcular expressoes matematicas constantes

Tags: c, matemática, parser

Tenho um trabalho para poder construir um algorítimo de que calcule expressões vindas de um arquivo TXT nesse formato.

10+20*(30)/ 25.

Sei que se trata de um analisador descendente recursivo, mas não tenho ideia por onde começar a estudar e como fazer a rotina de analise do programa.A linguagem utilizada é o querido C, materiais, dicas, são de boa ajuda.

Programa ate então.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void token(void) {




int main () {
char bse[100];
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("conta.txt", "r");
    if(file == NULL) {
         printf("Não foi possivel abrir o arquivo");
         getchar();
         exit(0);
    }     
    while(fgets(bse, 100, file) != NULL) { // Leitura e impressão do conteudo do arquivo TXT
         printf("%s", bse);
    }
    fclose(file);     



 }
```

Não fiz nada relacionado a o sintático recursivo descendente em si. Apenas fiz os comando de leitura do arquivo e armazenamento em uma string. Estou com duvidas em relação como fazer essa analise de expressões que seria a famosa (sintático recursivo descendente).

Comment: Você já tentou alguma coisa? Poste seu código se já.

Comment: Olá Razor! Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow! Por favor visite a [Central de ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) para saber mais sobre como perguntar e responder. Além disso, faça o [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)! No momento, sua pergunta me parece muito ampla - e normalmente a comunidade não dá sugestões de materiais (não é o propósito do site). Você já tem um compilador instalado? Já fez um "Hello, World!"? Qualquer início de programa fará com que a comunidade veja sua questão com outros olhos - experiência própria... ;)

Comment: Bem não fiz nada relacionado a o sintatico recursivo descendente em si. Apenas fiz os comando de leitura do arquivo e armazenamento em uma string. Estou com duvidas em relação como fazer essa analise de expressoes que seria a famosa (sintatico recursivo descendente.).

Comment: Pode ser que separar as operações por operador (+,*,/ -) seja um inicio. Depois considerar efetuar os cálculos seguindo a ordem precedência de operadores.

Comment: De boa - a não ser que você queira realmetne ficar muito bom em C, recomendo fazer esse tipo de programa em uma linguagem de mais alto nível (como Python). Ter métodos das strings para separar os tokens, estruturas de dados como listas (que podem ser usadas como filas) para colocar os operandos e operadores - podem facilitar sua vida em alguns anos luz, e você vai entender toda a lógica do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Em outra linguagem, você pode escolher, por exemplo, se vai querer parsear números "manualmente" - por exemplo, percorrento caractere a caratere, e se for dígito ir acumulando os digitos consecutivos num número, ou usar o método "split" de listas  e aplicar um "int()" nos tokens que tiverem ".isdigit()" como True - ou seja, você escolhe o quanto vai fazer de trabalho pra entender, e o quanto vai usar do que a linguagem tem pronta.

Em C, tem que fazer tudo do zero.

Comment: Estou no primeiro semestre, então a ideia é justamente essa, fazendo do zero para poder entender o que realmente ocorre com essas expressões. Irei estudar a Estrutura de Dados de PILHA, e utilizar a notação posfixa, pelo que eu vi é uma maneira mais fácil de se realizar o procedimento.

Comment: Relacionadas [1](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6382/receber-uma-express%C3%A3o-e-calcular-em-c) e [2](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88885/como-realizar-uma-express%C3%A3o-alg%C3%A9brica-em-uma-string-em-c#).

Answer (score 0):

Razor, já implementei algo parecido na disciplina de Compiladores, um pouco mais complexo pois o texto estava na forma escrita(Por exemplo: "trezentos e vinte e tres mil , duzentos e cinquenta e quatro mais quinze vezes dois"). Para esse implementação utilizei a linguagem Java com auxilio do Jflex ele é um analisador lexico. Segue o código principal, espero que ajude.

```
LineTerminator = \r|\n|\r\n
WhiteSpace     = {LineTerminator} | [ \t\f]

Number = [:digit:] [:digit:]*
pzero = "zero"
unidades = "um" | "dois" | "tres" | "quatro" | "cinco" | "seis" | "sete" | "oito" | "nove"
dezena = "onze" | "doze" | "treze" | "quatorze" | "quinze" | "dezesseis" | "dezessete" | "dezoito" | "dezenove"
dezenas = "vinte" | "trinta" | "quarenta" | "cinquenta" | "sessenta" | "setenta" | "oitenta" | "noventa"
pcem = "cem" | "duzentos" | "trezentos" | "catorze" | "quatrocentos" | "quinhentos" | "seiscentos" | "setecentos" | "oitocentos" | "novecentos"
centenas = "cento" | "duzentos" | "trezentos" | "quatrocentos" | "quinhentos" | "seiscentos" | "setecentos" | "oitocentos" | "novecentos"
dezuni = {dezenas}(" e "{unidades})
centdezuni = {centenas}( " e "{dezuni}) | {centenas}( " e "{dezenas}) | {centenas}( " e "{unidades}) | {centenas}( " e "{dezena})
juntos = {unidades} | {dezena} | {pcem} | {dezuni} | {centdezuni}
unidadedemilhar = {juntos}( " mil")( " , " {dezenas})*( " e " {unidades})* 
            | {juntos}( " mil")( " , " {pcem})
            | {juntos}( " mil")( " , " {centdezuni})


{WhiteSpace}+   { /* ignore */ }

<YYINITIAL> {
    {juntos}  { return newToken(Terminals.NUMBER, new String(yytext())); }
    {centdezuni}  { return newToken(Terminals.NUMBER, new String(yytext())); }
    {dezuni}    { return newToken(Terminals.NUMBER, new String(yytext())); }
    {pzero}    { return newToken(Terminals.NUMBER, new String(yytext())); }
    {pcem}    { return newToken(Terminals.NUMBER, new String(yytext())); }
{dezenas}    { return newToken(Terminals.NUMBER, new String(yytext())); }
    {dezena}    { return newToken(Terminals.NUMBER, new String(yytext())); }
    {centenas}    { return newToken(Terminals.NUMBER, new String(yytext())); }
    {unidadedemilhar}    { return newToken(Terminals.NUMBER, new String(yytext())); }

"("         { return newToken(Terminals.LPAREN); }
")"         { return newToken(Terminals.RPAREN); }
"vezes"         { return newToken(Terminals.MULT);   }
"dividido"         { return newToken(Terminals.DIV);    }
"mais"         { return newToken(Terminals.PLUS);   }
"menos"         { return newToken(Terminals.MINUS);  }
}
```

[image: Teste da implementação]

Resumindo para facilitar seu trabalho use algum analisador lexico, sei que existe algumas bibliotecas para C. Qualquer dúvida pode entrar em contato.